# DataGrid Column id's

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Quick one chaps,

If I have a datagridview control, lets call it 'tasklist'.

When I populate it, there are 3 columns, 'id', 'tasktitle' and 'owner'.
I dont want to show the 'id' on screen so I simply do:
        tasklist.Columns(0).Visible = False

Thats all good and the id column is not visible.

Does this then mean in terms of referencing the column numbers that 1 becomes 0 and 2 becomes 1?

or does the non-visable 'id' column retain the 0 id and 1 and 2 also stay the same?

Thanks!

Comment: They stay the same. This is pretty easy to test for yourself as well.

Comment: I thought that would be the case - I'm getting a weird error and when i tried testing myself i got a weirder error and it made me ponder, so I thought I'd ask the question to play safe. Thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not answer to question - just "better practice" for not using indexes(hard-coding).

Create predefined columns through designer.
Give a name for every column(for example: `task_id`, `task_title` and `task_owner`)

Then through designer you can set `Visible` property `task_id.Visible = false`(or in code)

Then in code(`Load event`) add `mydatagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false` - this will prevent datagridview generate columns

After this you can use your column without doubt about indexes

```
mydatagridview.Rows(0).Cells(task_owner.Name).Value = 'testowner'
```